# Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hpi.android.assetmanagement/com.hpi.android.assetmanagement.ui.detail.AssetDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.hpi.android.assetmanagement.ui.detail.AssetDetailActivity.onCreate(AssetDetailActivity.java:95)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ui.detail.AssetDetailActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/color"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Too broad, share your AssetDetailActivity layout at least

Comment: i'm share AssetDetailActivty.xml

Comment: you need to edit your original post, not posting it in an answer, I'll edit it ;)

Comment: i'm sorry first time to stack overflow

Comment: no prob, that's why we help you first by making a good post, to help people coming to help you ;)

Comment: i need help u. please answer my eror

Comment: I guess your error is here : `app:contentScrim="?attr/color"`

Comment: you should use `@color`

Comment: okey thanks, i'm try

Comment: Thank you for the advice. you are the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `app:contentScrim="?attr/color"`.

change it to `app:contentScrim="@color/YOUR_COLOR_NAME"` or remove the attribute `app:contentScrim` if you don't use it